# Creating Custom SessionStore for a django project

Tags: python, django

If I want to subclass a module such as `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore` so that I can override a lot of its default behaviour, what is the standard way of doing this in Django?

Suppose I create a file called `mydb.py`:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBSessionStore

class SessionStore(DBSessionStore):
    ...
```

If my project has this structure below, is it best practice to put, `mydb.py` in a `backends` directory under project's folder?

```
myproject
myproject/manage.py
myproject/myproject
myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
myproject/myproject/__init__.py
myproject/myproject/settings.py
myproject/myproject/urls.py
myproject/db.sqlite3
myproject/myapp
myproject/myapp/tests.py
myproject/myapp/admin.py
myproject/myapp/__init__.py
myproject/myapp/models.py
myproject/myapp/apps.py
myproject/myapp/migrations
myproject/myapp/migrations/__init__.py
myproject/myapp/views.py
myproject/myapp/urls.py
myproject/backends
myproject/backends/__init__.py
myproject/backends/mydb.py
myproject/__init__.py
```

Is `settings.SESSION_ENGINE='backends.db'` a reasonable standard to avoid namespace collisions? Is it a general rule of djamgo configurations that the current project is included in the python search path?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Put it where you like, and use that path in the settings.

Answer (score 5):

You should refer to it as to the file:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'python.path.mydb'
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#extending-database-backed-session-engines) is missing this little detail. In 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/sessions/middleware/ line 12 (django 1.9), you can find this:

```
self.SessionStore = engine.SessionStore
```

So it's literally taking the SessionStore class from engine you provided in `settings. SESSION_ENGINE`.